# Play a different audio each time play is pressed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an audio button that will play a different sound each time it is pressed. Right now, I have the play button, and the first sound is fine, but the sound does not update to the second sound after the first play.

```
    function update(audioElement) {
        audioElement.remove(); //get rid of old audio obj
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3'); //add new sound file
        $.get();
        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
            audioElement.play(); //bind new sound file
        }, true);
    }
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gD4Dr/1412/

Comment: Why not use an AudioSprite?

Comment: The issue I think would be updating the audio src which takes time to load.. Not sure though!

Comment: And besides its just mp3.. Firefox requires ogg I think.. Try adding two sources.. Check the documentation for audio tag

Comment: Do you need to destroy and create a new audio element each time? Plus, the load event has probably already ocurred before you try binding to it, so maybe do that first.

Comment: "`childNode.remove()` removes the object from the tree it belongs", here it's not in any tree and has no effect. Also you may want to delete it only in his `ended` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to recreate the `<audio>` element all the time. That is not necessary.

Check out the following mdn page for inforamtion on the [**<audio>**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element.

You do not have to load the file either. The file will be loaded automatically as soon as you set it as the `src` of the `<audio>` element.

[**Location of the media resource**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#concept-media-load-algorithm-at-creation)

> If a media element is created with a src attribute, the user agent must immediately invoke the media element's resource selection algorithm.
>
> If a src attribute of a media element is set or changed, the user agent must invoke the media element's media element load algorithm. (Removing the src attribute does not do this, even if there are source elements present.)

Here is an example of what you could do. Just check the comments and i'm sure you will get the idea.

```js
var audioFiles = ["http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg",
                  "foo/bar",
                  "http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3"
                 ], // files to play.
    $playBtn = $('.play'), // play button.
    $audioElem = $('<audio>'); // audio element.

// append the audio element to the body, only once.
$('body').append($audioElem);

// set src attribute of audio element to the next file in the list.
function playNextAudioFile() {
  // lets get the current file index using the current src attribute value.
  var crntFile = $.inArray($audioElem.attr('src'), audioFiles);
  // if there is none or if we are at the end of the list play the first file in the list.
  if (crntFile === -1 || crntFile === audioFiles.length - 1) {
    $audioElem.attr('src', audioFiles[0]);
    // else play the next file.
  } else {
    $audioElem.attr('src', audioFiles[crntFile + 1]);
  }
}
// listen for the click event on play button.
$playBtn.on('click', playNextAudioFile);

// listen for canplay event and start playing.
$audioElem.on('canplay', function() {
  $audioElem[0].play();
});
// start playing next file if prev file has ended.
$audioElem.on('ended', function() {
  $playBtn.click();
});
// start playing next file if an error occurred.
$audioElem.on('error', function() {
  $playBtn.click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="play">Play</button>
```

[**Here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) you can find information on the events being sent when dealing with embedded `<audio>` and `<video>` media elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg');
            $.get();
            audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
                audioElement.play();
            }, true);

            $('.play').click(function() {
                audioElement.play();
                audioElement = update(audioElement);
            });

        function update(audioElement) {
            audioElement.remove();
            var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3');
            return audioElement;    
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you got to use ended event capture to change the src url

```
audioElement.addEventListener("ended")



  $(document).ready(function() {
            var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg');
            $.get();
            audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
                audioElement.play();
            }, true);
    audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg');
                audioElement.play();
            }, true);
            $('.play').click(function() {
                audioElement.play();

            });

        function update(audioElement) {
            audioElement.remove();
            var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3');
            $.get();
            audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
                audioElement.play();
            }, true);
        }

    });
```